# Hard edge in Render

Tags: modeling

I want to create a backdrop for my renders. The normals are all okay and I created this curve between two planes with the spin tool and joined everything. In edit mode everything seems to be good. However in my Render I get a hard edge. Can someone please tell my why this is and how I can get rid of it?

It tried to subdivide the surface but it does not help...
[image]
[image: Hard edge visible]
[image: Normals orientated correctly]

Comment: that looks like doubles (i.e. 2 vertices/edges on top of each other). Did you try CTRL-M merge by distance?

Comment: I tried, unfortunately that's not it. Vertices look good. Nothing on top of each other. :(

Comment: Try to turn on Auto Smooth in the Mesh Properties.

Comment: @FFeller That already looks way better now! There is still some minor shading, but way better. Thanks!